# Is there a way in C to figure out if an expression is a struct or union?

Tags: c

I can determine that an expression is a floating point value (or an integer) with the otherwise fairly useless `_Generic` C11 feature. But is there a way to figure out, if something is a `struct` or a `union` at compile time ? For example, is there a a non-standard gcc feature that can help ?

Comment: What would you do with this ability if you had it?

Comment: Did you try `_Generic`?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, how can you write C code that uses it in the first place?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: With a `_Generic` that uses it one way if it is one thing and another way if it is another thing. E.g., one can write a `_Generic` that produces `abs(x)` if `x` is an `int` and `fabs(x)` if `x` is a `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Putting the code for a specific type called via `_Generic` still means you have to write the code for that specific type.  You still have to know what it is to write the code for it.

Comment: The idea is to *not* write code for it, in case it's a struct or union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `_Generic` to find if a variable `x` is of type `struct foo` or type `union bar`, but not to generically find if it is a `struct` or a `union` (and not care about which struct/union it is).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define get_type(x) _Generic((x), \
    struct foo: printf("%s = struct foo\n", #x), \
    union bar: printf("%s = union bar\n", #x), \
    default: printf("%s = something else\n", #x))

struct foo
{
    int x;
};

union bar
{
    int y;
};

struct baz
{
    int z;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct foo x;
    union bar y;
    struct baz z;
    get_type(x);
    get_type(y);
    get_type(z);
}
```

Output:

```
x = struct foo
y = union bar
z = something else
```

Comment: That's what I figured, but I was hoping that there might be maybe some obsure gcc feature, that I might have overlooked.